# Dispatch job with milliseconds delay

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unix-timestamp, laravel-queue

***TL;DR***

> *Can't dispatch jobs in Laravel with milliseconds delay, since `available_at` column is in unix timestamp format and doesn't support
> milliseconds.*

I use database driver for jobs and wanted to delay job dispatching. My algorithm requires me to dispatch jobs with **milliseconds delay** (say 100ms for example). In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) it is demonstrated with `->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));`. Also i noticed that job table's available at column is an integer column which is designated to be filled with unix timestamp.

When i dispatch my jobs with:

`MyJob::dispatch($jobSpecs)->delay(now()->addMilliseconds(1000));`

I can see that jobs differ in `available_at` values. Difference is 1 as in seconds as expected. However when i try to dispatch with 100ms  delay like so `->addMilliseconds(100)` i do not see any difference in available_at column value. I think it is an expected result since unix timestamp doesn't support milliseconds.

> It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, excluding leap seconds. The Unix epoch is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970

Therefore i am unable to dispatch with milliseconds delay. It actually dispatches just fine, but delay is not reflected to `available_at` column.

How can i workaround it ?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure how accurate you want the delay, but if a job is in a queue - there is no control over when it's executed.  It is more a case of it not being executed before that delay.

Comment: Even if there are no database column restrictions (you really should be using a different queue driver by the way). Queued jobs generally not precisely invoked when you want them to because there needs to be an available queue worker which decides to handle a job at that precise moment. Queue workers generally can process one job at a time and tend to also sleep for some time before handling the next job

Comment: @NigelRen AFAIK  it is possible to control when a job in queue will be executed through `available_at`. Worker's won't touch the job until job's `available_at`<=now()

Comment: But this doesn't mean it will be executed then, if the queue is busy it could take minutes or hours to be executed.  If it's such a short delay, you may be better off not queueing it.